# Is industrial organizational (I/O) psychology considered a STEM subject according to USCIS/DHS?

Tags: phd, united-states, psychology, stem

I'm looking to do a PhD in I/O psychology in the US. I learned that only a few psych subjects were considered STEM according to the [list released by ICE in 2016](https://www.ice.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Document/2016/stem-list.pdf) and I/O psychology is not one of them. However, on the list is "42.2799 Research and Experimental Psychology, Other". I'm wondering two things:

1. If this is the updated list
2. If a PhD in I/O Psych would be considered under "Other"

TIA!

Comment: Have you asked the institution what CIP code they're reporting this program as?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is the updated list, since it's linked from [here](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/stem-opt-hub/eligible-cip-codes-for-the-stem-opt-extension) for example. While that list doesn't name your field, there is a separate CIP code for Industrial and Organizational Psychology defined by the Department of Education. As you can see [here](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/cipcode/cipdetail.aspx?y=55&cipid=88060) it falls under category "42.28 Clinical, Counseling and Applied Psychology" rather than "42.27 Research and Experimental Psychology". The ICE list includes all categories under 42.27, but none under 42.28. As such, the major itself would not be classified as a STEM subject or eligible for STEM OPT. However, do check with the International Office of your potential US university. My speculation is that, depending on details of your program, it might be possible for them to classify you under another code.

Comment: Thank you @Anyon, that was very helpful!